# echo $variable > file in a loop outputs only the last value of variable

Tags: bash, io-redirection

Here's what I'm trying to do:
I have several git repos. I want to setup a push-to-deploy script for each of them. being so lazy to do that for each and every repo, I wanted to script it.

My script generates a post-receive file for each repo.

```
#!/bin/bash

REPOS=/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/user

for i in $(ls $REPOS)
do
        DEPLOY_DIR=/home/user/public_html/"$i"/
        POST_RECEIVE_DIR=$REPOS/"$i".git/hooks/post-receive

        echo -e '
from, to, branch = ARGF.read.split " "\r
\r
 # 3. Copy files to deploy directory\r
deploy_to_dir = File.expand_path('$DEPLOY_DIR')\r
`GIT_WORK_TREE="#{deploy_to_dir}" git checkout -f master`\r
puts "DEPLOY: master(#{to}) copied to '#{deploy_to_dir}'"\r
' > $POST_RECEIVE_DIR
        chmod +x $POST_RECEIVE_DIR

done
```

Notice that the only part that changes in the generated file is where $DEPLOY_DIR lies.
And $DEPLOY_DIR changes with each iteration.
The problem is: ALL the generated files have the LAST value of $DEPLOY_DIR.

To debug I tried to echo the variable values in various places in the script and they all produce the desired outputs. I thought it could be a problem with the buffers not being flushed. so I tried to use the sync command.
I tried using cat instead of echo. I tried to pass the file as a parameter to a python script where I write to the file and flush the buffer.

All failed to work.

Comment: Useless use of `$(ls $REPOS)`.  Better would be: `for i in $REPOS/*`.

Comment: @iamauser - how is that better?

Comment: Have you tried to write to one of these files manually, and see if all of them change?  They may all be symbolic links to the same file.  Otherwise, I would suggest you edit your answer, and try to walk us through creating a minimal scenario to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is hidden in your question.

```
 echo $variable > file in a loop outputs only the last value of variable
```

will obviously output the last value only.

instead the answer is

```
echo $variable >> file in a loop outputs all the values of variable
```

`>` overwrites a value while `>>` appends it. Therefore , if you are using only > in a loop , it will keep overwriting , and only the last value will be there in the file at the end

```
     ijaz@ijaz-HP-EliteBook-8560p:~$ echo hi>test1
     ijaz@ijaz-HP-EliteBook-8560p:~$ cat test1
     hi
     ijaz@ijaz-HP-EliteBook-8560p:~$ echo hello>test1
     ijaz@ijaz-HP-EliteBook-8560p:~$ cat test1
     hello
     ijaz@ijaz-HP-EliteBook-8560p:~$ echo hello1>>test1
     ijaz@ijaz-HP-EliteBook-8560p:~$ cat test1
     hello
     hello1
     ijaz@ijaz-HP-EliteBook-8560p:~$
```

Comment: this is incorrect - both forms output all values. at least, both forms do after first interpreting those values for `$IFS` splitting and shell globs by default, and, for a standard `echo`, for \\ backslash escapes as well.

Comment: no , a single >  in loop will overwrite the old value by the new one

Comment: indeed - it cant do that without output.

Comment: that's good. now can you do something about the `$IFS`, shell glob and `echo` backslash interpretations?

Comment: This answer addresses the OP’s title, but not the actual question.  If you look closely, you will see that each time OP uses `>`, it’s writing to a different file, and all the files end up undesirably having the same contents.

Comment: ya , i was just correcting the question :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have a quoting error somewhere.

Try using a "here document" to output the script:

```
    cat <<__EOF >"$POST_RECEIVE_DIR"
from, to, branch = ARGF.read.split " "

# 3. Copy files to deploy directory
deploy_to_dir = File.expand_path('$DEPLOY_DIR')
GIT_WORK_TREE="#{deploy_to_dir}" git checkout -f master
puts "DEPLOY: master(#{to}) copied to '#{deploy_to_dir}'"
__EOF
```

Also, what's with the `\r`s? Are you trying to write DOS files?

Comment: `echo` doesnt read stdin. it echoes arguments.

Comment: Sorry, should have used `cat`. Will edit the answer.

Comment: `cat -e` is not quite the same as `echo  -e`.